# Downloading free software directly from my website

Tags: internet

is it legal to have free softwares like VLC and Chrome to be download directly from my website? where the user would click o the icon for VLC for example and get the installer download without having to go the website for it.

Comment: You should specify what you mean by free.  VLC is under the GPL, Chrome is not so the answer is likely to be different between these two.

Comment: so this mean it would depend on the software. With Free I mean free to install and use. This is just for learning purposes

Comment: It would depend on the licence.  If that gives you distribution rights you can, if not you (probably) cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Just because software is free doesn’t mean it doesn’t come with conditions

All software is copyright and virtually none of it has entered the public domain. Therefore, the copyright owner can decide, usually through a licence, who can copy it and under what circumstances.

You need to read the licence applying to each piece of software to see if you can do this.